# How do I get involved with testing and QA with Ubuntu?

Tags: automation, testing, quality

I'd like to get involved with Ubuntu QA by creating automated tests. Is there an ongoing effort to create these tests? Where can I learn more?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The QA team does *extensive* automated testing - it's part of the requirements for hardware to get Ubuntu certified.

The project they use is [Checkbox](https://edge.launchpad.net/checkbox).  Don't be fooled by the quite cut-down version shipped in the `checkbox-gtk` package - the full suite contains a huge range of tests.

The [Ubuntu QA](http://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-qa) mailing list is where you want to go for checkbox questions, or to discuss merge requests. This [link](http://qa.ubuntu.com/automation/) discusses about the complete set of tools used by the QA team for automation.

Comment: Please add this link too: http://qa.ubuntu.com/automation/

Comment: @saji89: you can go ahead and suggest an edit.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple ways to get involved in writing automated tests. The quality team is involved in writing autopkg and autopilot tests for ubuntu packages.

**Autopkg**

Autopkg tests are run at build time automatically by the buildbots for the package. The goal of these tests is to provide system and integration testing to guarantee basic functionality. You can see the live output of the current autopkg tests [here](https://jenkins.qa.ubuntu.com/view/Raring/view/AutoPkgTest/). If your interested in writing these tests, see:

- [How do I contribute an autopkg test to ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236202/how-do-i-contribute-an-autopkg-test-to-ubuntu)

**Autopilot**

These tests are written in python using the autopilot framework. The goal of these tests is to provide higher level application and functional testing. The tests are written in python and can be user executed or scripted via a test runner such as UTAH or jenkins to run and publish results automatically. For more information on autopilot, check out the project on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/autopilot) as well as the [documentation](http://unity.ubuntu.com/autopilot/) for the project. If your interested in writing these tests, see:

- [How do I contribute an autopilot test?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233219/how-do-i-contribute-to-autopilot-tests)

**Getting Help**

For more information or to get help, email the [ubuntu-quality list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-quality) or visit #ubuntu-quality on freenode.

Answer (score 4):

A project does exist at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/Automation for this - I'm not sure how much it currently covers, but there is also automated upgrade testing done to test out upgrading various package combinations.

Answer (score 3):

You can get involved with testing by joining the [QA team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QATeam/), their [mailing list - ubuntu-quality](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-quality), and their [launchpad page](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/qa-r-autopilot-in-ue).

The last link will take you to the autopilot launchpad site which is thier automatated testing package.

See my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233219/how-do-i-contribute-to-autopilot-tests/233264#233264) for additional details on how Ubuntu automated testing works.

Answer (score 2):

Usually automated testing is done on a per project basis and the quality of those tests are highly dependant on the project's organisation and quality control. Tests can be tied into the building of debs and such but as far as I know I've never heard of any external testing framework outside of any particular project.

Answer (score 0):

There is http://qa.ubuntu.com/ - which links to e.g. http://mago.ubuntu.com/

While I cannot point at something specific, this appears to be a good starting point.