# How do I contribute an autopilot test?

Tags: automation, testing, quality

What is autopilot and how do I contribute to a new autopilot testcase for a package ?

Answer (score 6):

### What is Autopilot?

From the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/QA/Autopilot):

> *Autopilot is a functional testing tool for Unity. It simulates user actions by generating keyboard and mouse events, and then testing the internal state of Unity and associated applications.*

You can get involved with testing by joining the [QA team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QATeam/). Here is a link to their [mailing list - ubuntu-quality](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-quality), their [launchpad page](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/qa-r-autopilot-in-ue), as well as the official [Ubuntu QA page](http://qa.ubuntu.com/).

### Installation

To install Autopilot from the command line, run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:autopilot/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-autopilot
```

An example of a simple test unit:

```
autopilot run unity.tests.test_showdesktop.ShowDesktopTests.test_showdesktop_hides_apps
```

**Warning: 
Running autopilot tests on your default desktop will cause your pc to send mouse and keyboard movements without your control. Please read the articles below before blindly running this command.**

### Tutorials

There is a tutorial [here](http://unity.ubuntu.com/autopilot/). Additionally, there have been several good articles mentioned in the Ubuntu weekly newsletter. These were written by Nicholas Skaggs, a community coordinator on the testing team, that have been very useful for me.

[Autopilot: part 1](http://www.theorangenotebook.com/2012/11/a-glance-at-autopilot.html)

[Autopilot: part 2](http://www.theorangenotebook.com/2012/11/getting-started-with-autopilot.html) - Here the author walks through a simple "hello world" use case of autopilot

[Autopilot: part 3](http://www.theorangenotebook.com/2012/11/our-first-autopilot-testcase.html)

I highly recommend reading the three above linked articles before getting started with autopilot.

### Contributing Testcases

You can submit test cases by emailing the [ubuntu-quality mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-quality) using a specified format outlined [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/Activities).

Additionally, test cases can be pulled via bzr using the following command:

`bzr branch lp:ubuntu-autopilot-tests`

Adding test case changes to the code branch can be done with a bzr push comand:

`bzr push lp:<username>/ubuntu-autopilot-tests/ubuntu-autopilot-tests`

See http://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu-autopilot-tests for more information.

Comment: nice answer, I wouuld simply correct that there is now an official project for contributing testcases here -- can you update? Since it's a project, it's a simple branch and merge request setup :-)
https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu-autopilot-tests

Comment: @balloons Thanks. Is the email option deprecated? Please feel free to edit my response, as I expect you to have a more authoritative perspective.

Comment: will this work just for Unity or would it work in xubuntu or lubuntu ?

Comment: When in doubt, contact the test team either through the mailing list, or through IRC @balloons is a lead on testing and can point you in the correct direction if you join the team on IRC.