# Why is there no beta 1 release of Ubuntu?

Tags: release-management

Why is there no release of Ubuntu 14.04 Beta 1?

There is a release for all of the Ubuntu spin-off's (Xubuntu,Lubuntu,etc) but nothing specific to Ubuntu that I've found.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a Beta 1 iso? This questions has "answers" that direct you to daily lives. But if you're looking for something more stable than a daily live, you may want to make that explicit in your question. (Even as it is now, I think those "answers" could probably be converted to comments.)

Comment: Because it is only for opt-in flavours. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/08/ubuntu-14-04-lts-release-schedule

Answer (score 2):

Canonical have developed an ongoing method to continuously assess the progress of development called [AutoPilot Tests](http://qa.ubuntu.com/getting-involved/automated-tests/).

> [Autopilot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/QA/Autopilot) is a functional testing tool. It simulates user actions by
>   generating keyboard and mouse events, and then testing the internal
>   state of the application in question. It works for gtk and qt based
>   applications.

In summary, this involves various automated testing procedures to prove the viability of any changes to the build.

Canonical have stated that the extent of the automated testing has been [so successful](https://mail-archive.com/unity-dev@lists.launchpad.net/msg00064.html) that the normal [3 alphas/2 beta approach](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/foundations-r-schedule) to development that was so prevalent in earlier versions of Ubuntu is no longer required.  It could be construed that this is close to the "rolling release" version of Ubuntu - someone using this build always receives the latest versions of software during the overall cycle of development & testing.  Such a release is very well tested by the automated tests.

This approach [was seen](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QATeam/Cadence/Saucy) with the development Raring (13.04) and has continued with refinements for both Saucy (13.10) and especially for this LTS release.

As you can see from the [release schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule) - there is only one official beta release of Trusty - this coincides with beta 2 for the opt-in flavours of Ubuntu.

To provide flexibility for the differing development strategies for the various Ubuntu Desktop teams, the teams themselves nominate whether they wish to "opt-in" to this automated testing regime or to follow the more traditional point-in-time release strategy.  So far, only the Ubuntu desktop team has taken this approach.  However it should be remembered - for the vast majority of software and underlying software that is common, this automated approach benefits the wider eco-system - and indeed benefits Debian and Upstream - bugs are found more quickly and pushed upwards where necessary.

---

Linked Questions:

- [How do I contribute an autopilot test?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233219/how-do-i-contribute-an-autopilot-test)
- [How do I get involved with testing and QA with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127/how-do-i-get-involved-with-testing-and-qa-with-ubuntu?rq=1)