# How do I contribute an autopkg test to ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, testing, quality

How do I contribute an autopkg test for a ubuntu package?

Answer (score 4):

Autopkg tests can be written for any ubuntu package. The tests follow the [DEP 8 specification](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=autopkgtest/autopkgtest.git;a=blob_plain;f=doc/README.package-tests;hb=HEAD) for including tests as part of a deb package.

**Writing a test**

A test can be written in a myriad of languages. Common examples are C, bash, python and perl. To write a test:

1. Branch the package bzr branch ubuntu:
2. Add a source section in debian/control called XS-Testsuite: autopkgtest
3. Add the tests to debian/tests/ folder
4. Add a debian/tests/control which specifies the requirements for the testbed. For example:

> ```
> Tests: build
> Depends: build-essential
> ```

**Contributing tests**

Getting the test into ubuntu follows the normal ubuntu developer process. In short, you

1. Branch the source of the package you wish to add a test
2. Edit the debian/control and debian/tests/control file to enable the tests
3. Add the test(s) to debian/tests folder
4. Commit your changes and propose a merge

**More information**

To see a list of current autopkgtests, you can see the live jenkins output of all the tests that are currently being automatically run [here](https://jenkins.qa.ubuntu.com/view/Raring/view/AutoPkgTest/).

In addition, the ubuntu developer documentation has further information on [contributing an autopkg testcase](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/auto-pkg-test.html), including examples of tests.